Is an app expiration date a viable alternative to Google subscriptions?
I am turning a web-app into a mobile app, starting with Android. For a couple different reasons listed below I want use of the app to be subscription based (eg a couple bucks a year to use it). I am finding the Google/Play Store in-app subscription process a "little" daunting for my limited patience and brainpower for something that seems like it should be fairly simple to implement. I will probably end up turning to one of the third-party options (eg RevenueCat), but it occured to me that maybe hardwiring an end date into the app's functionality was at least a possibility.
The reasons I want it to be subscription based and think an expiration date might be a good idea include: It is mostly seasonal in use so a firm expiration date of when it is not generally being used shouldn't be a real problem; It relies on data from a lot of sources I do not control that may vanish at any time; I am the opposite of young and I could vanish or be unable to maintain at any time. By having an expiration date that is fully disclosed I would not feel guilty if I was unable to maintain or keep up with things beyond a certain point.
So I was thinking something along the lines of Excel (eg 2016, 2019, 2021) or Madden (eg every year), where I know those technically work into the future one has to purchase a new one to get all the latest.
I realize that for each yearly incarnation I would have to do some leg-work of changing app package names and creating a new app in Play Store etc. instead of just posting an update, but that seems fairly trivial compared to dealing with the Google Billing subscriptions process.
I scrubbed the internet relentlessly and saw very few mentions of app expiration dates which makes me think this maybe shouldn't be a thing, but I don't know why.
What am I missing? Downsides or something that is just escaping me..
I tried understanding Google Billing API subsciption docs and realized I was in over my head.

what would stop a user from changing the date of the device back so they could keep on using the app. If you cant do it right, dont do it at all

tyczj at least in my head this would be compared to current date/time ie from java, is that something users can manipulate?

All they have to do is go into the device settings and change the date
